# Diagnosing a Sporadic Django/ Postgres "DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted"

Tags: django, postgresql, transactions

I have a "DatabaseError: current transaction is aborted" that comes and goes (to be specific, 11 times out of 841) in a Django 1.3 project using Postgres. The project is a quiz site and the error occurs when a user submits the answer form in the view. From the database's perspective, the process involves a number of queries and looks like this:

1. Gather all of the correct answers for the question (they are multiple choice and may need more than one answer)*
2. Grab the user's profile
3. Save this answer
4. Query for the user's new point total
5. Save the total to their profile
6. Check to see if they qualify for a new reward
7. Award new reward if they do

Somewhere in that tortured process, this error crops up (I'm guessing because one query isn't waiting for the others). Is there a way for me, in production (i.e., DEBUG = False), to log the database errors just in this case? I'm on WebFaction and the [Postgres error logs are not available to me](http://community.webfaction.com/questions/2446/databaseerror-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-transaction-block). Could I steal something from this [middleware example](http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/290/) to fire in just this specific case?

Alternatively, is there a better way to find this error or should I be wrapping the individual queries in transactions (unfortunately they aren't all in the same place in the code, not sure if wrapping the view in a transaction decorator would help)?

*Just to confuse matters, the multiple right answers requirement was added in the middle of development and then dropped right before we went live, so I could simplify this process somewhat, basically skipping steps 1 and 4, but I'd like to know a general answer to this sort of mysterious issue.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said where in your 7 steps you have transactions that begin and end. That would be helpful to know.

One source of "transaction aborted" messages is due to deadlocks. More details would be in the PostgreSQL logs.

But the bottom line is that you will continue to have a painful and time-consuming experience debugging PostgreSQL if you can't get access to your PostgreSQL error messages. Take that up with WebFaction. If they can't helpful and your time is worth much, your bottom line costs will be lower by moving to an environment that provides this fundamental feature.

Comment: I don't have any transactions controls on it currently.

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable autocommit for the transaction. In your `DATABASES` entry, include:

`'OPTIONS':  {'autocommit': True,},`

By default, Django opens a transaction at the first query. By using this option, you manually have to start a transaction (e.g. using `@commit_on_success`). Since there is no transaction open anymore, you'll get the actual error that was previously masked by the transaction error.

The autocommit setting will be the new default for Django 1.6, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/databases/#postgresql-notes